# Why my full-wave bridge type diode rectifier circuit begins an analysis from 8. second on Matlab Simulink?

Tags: diodes, rectifier, matlab, power-electronics

[image: Simulink Error Screen]

Hi, I am working on Matlab Simulink's work page to get full-wave and half-wave bridge-type-diode rectifiers as could be seen in the picture. But, according to my Scope2 screen when I double clicked from simulink white-area **it begins from 8. seconds not from zero??** How can I made it to begin with zero point to analysis?

AC voltage: 50HZ Vpp-max=10Volt 
RLC Load: only Resistance 1KiloOhm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right! I found my fault:

1. Double click on *Continuous* block
2. On Simulation and configuration options
3. Configure parameters
4. Preferences
5. Start simulation with initial electrical states from "ZERO"

I chose Blocks, now it is Zero. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the simulation set to run for 10 seconds, and the scope is showing you the last two seconds.

Note that for analyzing AC circuits, it's often best to look at data after all the responses to initial conditions have died away (of course, keeping in mind that they're there and may be important.